# How to check if a table valued parameter is empty or not inside of a where clause?

Tags: sql-server, parameters

I am writing a function where I am passing a table valued parameter.
In some of the cases table valued parameter can be empty.

So, my function looks like below-

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testTableValueParam]
(   
    @created_date datetime = null
    ,@Ids dbo.IdList readonly
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
     SELECT top 10
            name
            ,scores
            ,mgr_name

        from dbo.employee
        where
            created_date = @created_date
            and 
            employeeId in (select empid from @Ids)           --ignore this condition when @Ids is empty. 
)
```

My table type is created as below-

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE(
    [empid] [nvarchar](11) NULL
)
```

I am calling my function from a c# code.
There are cases when the table value parameter will be empty and in those cases, when the table value parameter is empty, i want to ignore the condition in where clause.

I went through some of the links while searching my answer and the answers suggested in earlier posts didn't fix my problem.

So, right now, when @Ids parameter is empty, it gives me no record.
In some of the post they suggested not to pass a parameter for table value at all, and it will automatically treat it as an empty table.
But I have cases when I need to pass the parameter with data.
Some of the answers suggested, using `if exist(select 1 from @Ids)`
But, I can not use if exist in my where clause.

Please provide any suggestions.
Your responses are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't a quick fix be check for the Ids before going into your select statement? if Ids is empty select... with no where clause else select with where clause

Comment: The solution provided by M.Ali should work. I would also point out that you have a top 10 but no order by. That means the order will not always be the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` operator something like....

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testTableValueParam]
(   
    @created_date datetime = null
    ,@Ids dbo.IdList readonly
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
     SELECT top 10
            name
            ,scores
            ,mgr_name

        from dbo.employee
        where
           (@created_date IS NULL OR created_date = @created_date)
            and 
              ( 
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Ids) 
                OR
                employeeId in (select empid from @Ids)
              )            
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testTableValueParam]
(   
    @created_date datetime = null
    ,@Ids dbo.IdList readonly
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
     SELECT top 10
            name
            ,scores
            ,mgr_name
    from dbo.employee
    where
        created_date = @created_date
        and 
        ((select count(*) from @Ids) < 1  or  employeeId in (select empid from @Ids))
        employeeId in (select empid from @Ids)           --ignore this condition when @Ids is empty.
```

)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testTableValueParam]
(   
    @created_date datetime = null
    ,@Ids dbo.IdList readonly
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
     IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Ids)
     BEGIN
         SELECT TOP 10
                name
                ,scores
                ,mgr_name
            FROM dbo.employee
            WHERE created_date = @created_date
                AND employeeId in (select empid from @Ids)           --ignore this condition when @Ids is empty. 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 10
                name
                ,scores
                ,mgr_name
            FROM dbo.employee
            WHERE created_date = @created_date
    END
)
```

Comment: You cannot have `IF..ELSE` block inside an Inline table valued function hence the answer is wrong.